# QGIS Cascading WMS not working from secure WMS

Tags: qgis, wms, authentication, url

I am using QGIS Server (3.12.1) to cascade WMS's from the web.

I am bringing in Open Source XYZ tile connections to QGIS Desktop with no password required and serving them back out as WMS from QGIS server.
This is working fine when I save it in the project file folder.
Example: When I add a WMS/WMTS in a browser/QGIS desktop/ArcMap in the format:
https://SERVERNAME:8081/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?MAP=MyMapName.qgz all data is displaying fine.

I am also bringing in a WMS from a secure site which requires a username and password.
The WMS connects perfectly with the username and password into QGIS desktop. I have imported the WMS with a saved configuration password (encrypted) and basic password (plain text) and it comes into QGIS desktop fine so I can save the project file.
When I try calling the WMS from QGIS sever from the (C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\bin) project file I get a server 500 error.
I use the same format as above for Open Source: https://SERVERNAME:8081/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?MAP=MyMapName.qgz
and have tried get capabilities requests also.

I have tried adding the password at the calling QGIS server WMS end and this does not work.

I am pretty sure it is an authentication issue but I am stuck to know where do I include the username and  password.

I have tried including the user/password in the request URL in a number of combinations but no luck so far.
https://SERVERNAME:8081/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe&MAP=MyMapName.qgz&~username=username&password=MyPassword

Do you have any recommendations or suggestions?